# Pandas groupby and then pandas cut in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I was having some issues trying to use pd.cut after a groupby.

My dataframe looks like:

```
ID TEAM AGE
01  A    25
02  B    32
03  C    25
04  A    60
```

What I want to do is groupby by TEAM and then cut and count how many people are in each cut (for each team)

So I expect something like this

```
TEAM  CUT    COUNT
  A   0-10     2
  A   11-19    5
  B   0-10     1
```

And so on..

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
x_m = indmujeres.groupby('Radio')[['Edad']].transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70],labels=['0-10',"11-19",'20-29',"30-39","40-49","50-59",'60+']))
```

Where:
Radio = Team and Edad = Age

I`m obtaining a dataframe with only the labels with no clue about the Radio value

Any suggestion helps!

Comment: Construct a dataframe that also has a column containing your age labels. Then it's just a matter of a single `.groupby()` on two columns.

Comment: Just a quick comment on the cut. Your labels are not exactly correct. `cut` function has `right == True` default meaning it creates `(edge, next_edge]` ranges. These labels would be. `['1-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61+']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `cut`, then aggregate:

```
(df.assign(CUT=pd.cut(df['AGE'], right=False,
                      bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
                      labels=['0-10',"11-19",'20-29',"30-39","40-49","50-59",'60+'])
                 .astype('string')
          )
   .groupby(['TEAM', 'CUT'], as_index=False).agg(COUNT=('CUT', 'count'))
)
```

Output:

```
  TEAM    CUT  COUNT
0    A  20-29      1
1    A    60+      1
2    B  30-39      1
3    C  20-29      1
```

Comment: This work perfectly. Thank you! It was a bit harder than I expected, time to keep learning I guess.